# How do I make the makemessages command detect default django translations (like form validation error messages)?

Tags: django, django-forms, localization, internationalization, django-validation

The site I'm developing is multilingual and the secondary language is not supported by default. I have added it in the settings file like so.

```
    EXTRA_LANG_INFO = {
    'am': {
        'bidi': False, # right-to-left
        'code': 'am',
        'name': 'Amharic',
        'name_local': u'አማርኛ', #unicode codepoints here
    },
}
```

The error_messages that I overwrite and use are correctly translated and detected by the makemessages command.

```
error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _('The two password fields didn’t match.'),
    }
```

But the default validation exception error_messages that I did not overwrite do not appear in the .po translation file.
It would be much easier to find out a way to make the command also render translations for those strings, as opposed to me overriding on every time it appears. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kidus, sorry to say that, but Django does not include the default messages in your .po file.

Comment: So I guess I have to manually overwrite all of them right? Thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: When I get you right, you don't want to additionally write translations for strings that are already translated by default, right? If so, you don't need to translate these strings. They are not in your .po file and get detected at runtime from djangos provided default translations. E.g. you don't need to translate `_('User')` on your own.

Comment: The problem is that the second language is not supported by Django officially so I need to provide more translations for the default string.